# Wordpress ACF and slick slider link on image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, slick.js

I have Slick Slider built in with ACF in wordpress, the images and slider work, trying to now wrap the image in a link so each image can link out to a set page.
at the moment it just links to the home url, Im not sure what im doing wrong in the code, any help is useful.

```
  <h3 class="pb-3"><?php the_field('slider-text', false, false) ?></h3>
<div id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr($className); ?>">
    <?php if (have_rows('slides')): ?>
        <div class="slides"
             data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 5, "slidesToScroll": 1, "autoplay": true, "autoplaySpeed": 2000, "dots": true}'>
            <?php while (have_rows('slides')): the_row();
                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                $link = get_sub_field('link');
                ?>
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="<?php ($link['id']); ?>">
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image['id'], 'full'); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `($link['id'])` seems you are missing an `echo` or `get_permalink($link['id'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link['id'] ); ?>">`

You need to print the url to display in the output, also added abit of sanitization for safe measure!

Comment: cheers, not working as of yet but my ACF is not keeping url after set, so will check for mistake my end, but looks good thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer from my comment:

You aren't doing anything with the `(link['id'])` - that's why it's redirecting to the same page it's on - the `href` is empty.

You need to pass that link ID into `get_permalink()`

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($link['id']); ?>">
```

Comment: am trying atm, for some reason acf dose not save the link

Comment: Right after `$link = get_sub_field('link');` in your code, do `var_dump( $link )` and post what you get.

Comment: good shout, always forget to debug properly

Comment: getting NULL, this is strange.